# statsmodel AttributeError: module 'scipy.stats' has no attribute 'chisqprob'

Tags: python, scipy, statsmodels

I'm running the code below with statsmodel 0.8.0 which i believe is the latest.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
est = sm.Logit(y_train, x_train)
result = est.fit()
print(result.summary())
```

This is giving me an error saying:

AttributeError: module 'scipy.stats' has no attribute 'chisqprob'.

I dont seem to be able to find anything on stackoverflow or elsewhere to resolve this. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: See https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/3931

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try this:

```
result.summary2()
```

Link:

> http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.LogitResults.summary2.html?highlight=summary2#statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.LogitResults.summary2

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but this solved it. However, you first need to import stats from scipy.

```
stats.chisqprob = lambda chisq, df: stats.chi2.sf(chisq, df)
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options.
Either use,

```
> result.summary2()
```

or you can import chisqprob.

```
> from scipy import stats

> stats.chisqprob = lambda chisq, df: stats.chi2.sf(chisq, df)
```